# Joining nested and unnested data frames/tibbles

Tags: r, join, tidyverse, tibble

I think I dont fully understand nested tibbles (data frames) and how they behave when joined to "normal", i.e., non-nested tibbles.

### Example:

```r
## Create a list and a data frame
ll <- list(matrix(rnorm(4), nrow = 2), matrix(rnorm(4), nrow = 2))
ll
#> [[1]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 1.7299068 0.1577844
#> [2,] 0.7156288 0.6265956
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            [,1]       [,2]
#> [1,] -0.5285925  1.0423880
#> [2,] -0.1524862 -0.3887486
df <- data.frame("name" = 1:2, "b" = c(0.4, 0.6))
df
#>   name   b
#> 1    1 0.4
#> 2    2 0.6

# Now I want to:
#  1. Create a nested data frame/tibble. 
#  2. Join df and the newely created nested data frame/tibble 
#
# There are many ways to create a nested tibble, a convinient one is:
df_nested <- tibble::enframe(ll)
df_nested
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    name value            
#>   <int> <list>           
#> 1     1 <dbl[,2] [2 x 2]>
#> 2     2 <dbl[,2] [2 x 2]>

# looks as expected

# Now when I try to join (merge(), cbind() and other join_* verbs are similar)
dplyr::left_join(df, df_nested, by = "name")
#>   name   b                                         value
#> 1    1 0.4    1.7299068, 0.7156288, 0.1577844, 0.6265956
#> 2    2 0.6 -0.5285925, -0.1524862, 1.0423880, -0.3887486
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Question:

Why doesnt `left_join()` preserve the nested structure. Or differently: what
do I have to do in order to keep the nested structure after joining?

Both, a simple and a more elaborate answer as to why the nested structure is not preserved here are welcome.

Comment: The nested structure is preserved in your example, unless I'm missing something? It is only the print method that makes it appear as one vector. See `str(dplyr::left_join(df, df_nested, by = "name"))`, or print just the resulting `value` column. If you convert to a `tibble`, the print method makes it bit clearer that you still have matrix elements in `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `df` data frame to a tibble before the join:

```
df <- dplyr::as_tibble(df)
```